# Word 2010 Macro shortcut using Normal.dotm

Tags: macros, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2003

I have a macro that needs to be run from the shortcut button. I have added that shortcut in word 2003 & 2010 manually without breaking a sweat. Now in word 2003 if I add a shortcut it got saved in Normal.dot file & if I copy-paste that Normal.dot file in another pc that Macro-Shortcut comes up without any extra effort. But that's not the case for word 2010.

I need to do the same thing for word 2010. What can I do?

I am describing my project requirement below, any workaround is appreciated:
I have to provide a macro to my clients, right now I'm saving my macro in a Normal.dot file & then running a batch file which overwrites Word's Normal.dot file. Now I need to show a shortcut for this macro.

Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Copying the Normal.dot from Word 2003 for direct use in Word 2010 is not recommended. You could instead rename your template something else and put it in your [Word Startup Folder](http://moreaddin.com/faqs/where-is-words-startup-folder.html). This would make it a [global template](http://www.addbalance.com/word/global_templates.htm) and give access to macros and keyboard shortcuts in Microsoft Word 2010.